# How can I get some characters from a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, save, character, filenames

I'm trying to save an excel file using vba and I want the filename from that file to be some characters found in cell A3.

Let's say my cell A3 has the next number 2420561300, I want that my filename gets only the first 6 characters from that number to be its name: 242056.

I have the following code:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
.Title = "Please choose where to save the file and a name to it"
.ButtonName = "Save Excel"
Set rng = Range("A3").Value
.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & rng
If .Show = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File was not saved.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```

From this code I get the filename to be the whole number but how can I get only some characters from that Range().Value?
Thank you for your answers. I have checked several posts but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Try `Left(Range("A3").Value, 6)`. And `Set rng = Range("A3").Value` is not correct if `rng` has been declared `As Range`. At least, if you like it to be a range. Otherwise, VBA may consider it as `Variant`... Anyhow, try declaring all your variables. Put `Option Explicit` on top of your module!

Comment: Thank you so much @FaneDuru, that worked perfectly!! I can't believe it was something that simple, thank you!

Comment: The correct way to set a `Range` is `Set rng = Range("A3")`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take that into account too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to directly `SaveAs` a workbook, you can proceed in this way:

```
Dim fullFilename As String
fullFilename = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & left(Range("A3").value, 6) & ".xlsx"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fullFilename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

The above code assumes that your `Range("A3")` does not contain the extension, too. If it contains, last part of the `fullFilename` definition must be deleted.

If you insist to use dialog and make it show the name to be saved, please use:
`.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Left(Range("A3").Value, 6) & ".xlsx"`

Answer (score 0):

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
.Title = "Please choose where to save the file and a name to it"
.ButtonName = "Save Excel"
.InitialFileName = "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\" & Left(Range("A3").Value, 6)
If .Show = 0 Then
    MsgBox "File was not saved.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
End With
```

@FaneDuru gave me the correct answer in the comments, thank you so much. It was just adding `Left(Range("A3").Value, 6)`

Comment: But this is a Dialog and in what you show, you can set the folder where the dialog to be initially shown. If you need to `SaveAs` for a specific name, I can show you how. Anyhow, your above code misses a `End With`... Whit what extension do you like to save? xlsx? You must know that when save something...

Comment: Oh yes sorry I forgot to put the `End With`. Yes sorry, I forgot to mention that too, I made it a dialog so you can choose where to save it and the filename, but I wanted the initial filename to be like that in the dialog as most names will have that format. And yes I wanted to saved it xlsx as I want all macros to dissapear, that code is only a part of the whole code. No problem, I solved the rest, I only needed to see how to save some characters from a cell as a filename, thank you!

Comment: If you want to save in a specific location and you know it, you loose time using the dialog, but it is only an opinion...

Comment: I know but the thing is the location may vary from different files so I prefer give the dialog so the person can choose where to save it.